# How can I get the caret's position in xaml?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer, caret

I have a few textboxs and I want to achieve this funcion: when tap into each textbox, that specific textbox will move to the top and when user type in some data it can auto scroll and keep the cursor|caret always on top of the screen. I know that I can use`ScrollViewer.ChangeView(null,offset,null);` to set the view, however, how can I get the cursor's position (y or vertical offset) though. This is WP 8.1 app.

Comment: What cursor are you expecting there to be on the phone?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I used IBeam, which is something like "|", but I don't know how to get it's position.

Comment: Do you mean the **caret** then, not the *cursor*?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes...I didn't know that it has the same name as ^

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for the WPF `TextBox` class [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx), there is a property called `CaretIndex` which "Gets or sets the insertion position index of the caret."

You might also be able to use the value of the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties to find where the caret is, but if the `SelectionLength` is larger than zero, that might not work.  Try the `CaretIndex` property.

Comment: Thank you, but the position I want is actually vertical offset or (x,y)'s Y value. Because I want to move that textbox up, then I need to know how much vertical offset there is to scroll using Control.ChangeView(null,verticaloffset,null)

Comment: WPF does not work that way, unless you're using a Canvas as your container.  You're better off using a `Grid` and changing the `Grid.Row` attached property on each `TextBox`. Then you won't have to worry about coordinates

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand your requirement. Currently there is no property/method to get the current caret position in the text. But if you want to move your caret at the start of the textbox than use below code.

```
  txtbox.SelectionStart = 0;
  txtbox.SelectionLength = 0;
```

**Edit**

By using txtbox SelectionStart and textbox selection length you can get caret position.

```
  int caretIndex = txtbox.SelectionStart + txtbox.SelectionLength;
```

Comment: I need to get the postion of the caret so that I can scroll to that position. Thanks any way!

Comment: see my edit to get caret position using selectoinstart and selectionLength properties. thanks to @Tony Vitabile :)

Comment: Thank you, but the position I want is actually vertical offset or (x,y)'s Y value.